# Characteristics of a family of partially coupled linear oscillators

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the second-order initial value problem, defined for a function $u:R\to R^n$:

$$\ddot{u} = -(I + A)u$$
$$\dot{u}(t=0) = \dot{u}_0$$
$$u(t=0) = u_0$$

In the case where $A=0$, this reduces to each component of $u$ being an independent sinusoid. Does this problem have a name for the case when $A \neq 0$? If so, are there known conditions that $A$ must satisfy for $u$ to not either diverge or converge to $0$ as $t\to\infty$?

Comment: For $A=0$ each component is exponential, you might want to add a minus sign. You can apply a transformation to Jordan normal form, so that then $A=D+N$, $AN=NA$, $N^n=0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you for your correction and comment! Can you elaborate on this a bit? E.g., does the decomposition here give us the ability to predict asymptotic behaviour of the system? Particularly, e.g., if we can constrain the norm of $A$?

Comment: Is $A$ constant, symmetric, small? If $A$ is not constant, then the Jordan decomposition is less helpful. If $A$ is symmetric, then for small $A$ there is a unique square root of $I+A$. If $A$ is not small, then giving the factor as $I+A$ makes no sense, just use a simple matrix factor.